# Horizontal line throughout HTML page

Tags: html, css

I like to put a line throughout HTML page. How to do this?

[image]

I tried:

```
hr {
    width: 100%;
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Hmm? It looks like it is working in your screenshot.

Comment: You could use a thin height `DIV` for that purpose.

Comment: @Abody97: Yes, I want to do like that. Sorry it is not the result of my code.

Comment: if you need to display the ruler on the outer of the body, you can add `css` for the `<body>` tag as `border-bottom:2px solid #333;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<hr />` tag is always of `100%` width of its parent tag.

```
<br />​<hr />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<br />​​​​​
```

Check if the parent has some `padding` which you need to remove. Another option is to set the `body` tag's `padding` and `margin` to `0`.

```
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

**Complete code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            } 
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <br />
    </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: out of HTML ? @Emerald214 what does it mean? you mean it should cover the full display?

Comment: I have pasted the complete code now. Tested in Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Check these Demos...

[**http://jsfiddle.net/dqnKQ/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/dqnKQ/1/)  And  **http://jsfiddle.net/dqnKQ/2/**

Answer (score 1):

## Just type `<hr />`, it works great

You can always style it inline if need be.
for example:

```
<hr style="width:100%; height:6px; background-color: #cce1ec; border:none;" />
```

As an HTML tag it can also be used as a selector in CSS,
for example:

```
hr{ width:100%; height:6px; background-color:#cce1ec; border:none;}
```